# Transferring images captured by iPhone onto the WebService

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

This is what I am trying to accomplish.

1. Capture images from iPhone
2. Store them on the web service
3. Retrieve them when required

I have searched for tutorials on the topic but have found none. Also, there are various threads providing information in bits and pieces which I am finding hard to piece together and deduce something useful from. Please post a sample code that does it.

Thanks in advance.

Sayeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your trying to upload to a popular web service like Flickr, you will have to read and understand their API. Whether your using one of those, or your own server, most probably you'd want to use this open-source library [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) as it will provide you with a nice layer of abstraction with communicating with web services.

Answer (score 0):

To capture images you can use the [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)
To up- and download images to/from a web server you can use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) and it's companion.

And it's always a good start to look into some apple sample codes. They're on the related classes documentation at the top under "Related sample code".

Comment: Hey V1ru8,

I have checked the sample codes you mentioned. I hate to say this, but I have not found any codes that elaborates on what I wish to accomplish. I understand that I am asking for being spoon fed.

Comment: This is not just a few lines of code. And it depends a lot on how the server looks like.

And the URL Loading System Programming Guide really describes most of the stuff you need. The 'SimpleURLConnections' and the 'AdvancedURLConnections' have good examples.

For the upload yo use a POST request and for the download a GET.